# Recommended way of scaling firebase by adding regions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

At present I have 3 firebase projects used for an app: live, beta, development

These handle respective environments and are all within US zone.

In the future if app is used world wide, what is the recommended way to scale in EU / Asia + US? My initial instinct is to create additional firebase projects like live-eu, live-asia, but I see an issue here:

Can these projects use same app id that my US ones are currently using? I can't import data from US project as it has `uid's` in there, surely these wont work with auth from other projects? But I'd need to allow users to transition into other regions.

I won't be able to gather analytics from all regions in one place as well correct?

Hence the question, is there a way to scale / add multi region support in on a firebase project? Particularly interested in firestore and cloud functions, as these are the ones where latency can be reduced.

Comment: Yea that is something I do not understand as well. I know the buckets for storage can have multiple regions, but the database/cloud functions only 1 region. They state that you should put your database and cloud functions in the region where your users will be. But where to put it if I target both EU and US users? :(

Comment: Might be helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/OlBQAFMdomY

Comment: Is your solution write or read intensive? If it's read intensive, you should look for cache mechanisms at the edge level.

Comment: This question should be reworded to avoid requesting opinions/recommendations or it is likely to be closed as "Primarily opinion based". I think the intent of this question is fine, but should be asked as a 'what are my options?' question, as opposed to 'what do you recommend?' or 'what is considered best practice?'. You're also likely to get more answers that way.

Comment: @3D1T0R If you are a firebase user and read the question properly, you will get what his actual question.

Comment: @AngusTay Unfortunatly not everyone on this site is a firebase user so it's best to avoid any unwanted confusion. Also this question looks too broad to me, I'm counting atleast 5 different questions in there.

Comment: @AndréKool that is why I ask him to read the question again, the question is clearly stated, and that is why tagging playing a vital role here, only domain expert will look into the problem.  It's just like a MS Word expert with no prior DL knowledge commenting on a Deep Learning problem.  It's different domain.

Comment: I am familiar with firebase, and I understood what was being asked in this question from the beginning: as I said "I think the intent of this question is fine"; on the other hand questions which ask for opinions and recommendations are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow, and I'd rather see the question rewritten to avoid sounding like it's asking for opinions and/or recommendations than see this question closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked in the comments but didn't get a response, so I'm assuming that your app has a READ intensive workload. For these cases, in order to reduce latency of requests coming from all over the world, you should make use of a CDN to cache static files and responses (i.e. make use of edge locations and edge computing). You don't even need to stick with Firebase for that (there are solutions like Akamai and CloudFront that may fit your needs and easily plug to your Firebase solution), but if you need to, take a look at [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/).

If your workload is WRITE intensive, try to make use of asynchronous mechanisms, such as messaging queue, to guarantee that you give a faster feedback to the user. Usually, write operations don't need to be immediately/synchronously executed, but again, it would be good to understand your workload to give a more precise answer.

EDIT: Google recently announced [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) -- they offer multi-region support for better availability:

> A multi-region location is a general geographical area, such as the United States. Data in a multi-region location is replicated in multiple regions. Within a region, data is replicated across zones.

In terms of scalability, this is the statement they gave in [their blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html):

> Cloud Firestore [...] is built on top of the same Google Cloud infrastructure that powers some pretty popular apps. So it will be able to scale much more easily and to a much greater capacity than the Realtime Database can.
>
> And with the new querying structure, all Cloud Firestore queries scale to the size of your result set -- not the size of your data. This means that a search for the top 10 restaurants in Chicago for a restaurant review app will take the same amount of time whether your database has 300 restaurants, 300 thousand or 30 million. As one engineer here likes to put it, "It's basically impossible to create a slow query in Cloud Firestore."

Note that writes in Firestore have strong consistency (meaning they have higher latency compared to eventual consistency solutions).

Comment: My use case involves both really, its a game, so a lot of writes and reads happen, I also don't believe that caching would do any good here i.e. player data like equipement and stats will change frequently :/

Comment: Have you considered Firestore? https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html?m=1

Comment: I did, but isn't it also tied to one region i.e. one of your project?

Comment: They say in the documentation that is multiregion, however is in Beta.

Comment: Thats true, but I believe it refers to availability in multiple regions, but once your project has a region you can't change it per user, correct?

Comment: Correct, you can't change -- replication is transparent. Note that there's no silver bullet, as I said in my post. That's the reason why big game platforms have region-lock or offer their games as multi-region.

Comment: Also, having an intensive write and read game will increase your costs -- better choose carefully what really needs to be sent to the server and what can be done at the client level. I'll update the post talking about Firestore -- they say in their documentation that queries are optimized, but they have strong consistency for writes, so even if you choose to run Firestore as multiregion, some latency is expected (as opposed of having an eventual consistency solution).